# Ler um BLOB correspondente a uma imagem

Tags: c#, wpf, longblob

O código seguinte utiliza o MySqlDataReader para obter um registo específico da base de dados:

```
string cmd = string.Format("Select * from socios.socio WHERE idSocio={0}", chave);
MySqlCommand comandoMySQL = new MySqlCommand(cmd, ligacaoBD);
MySqlDataReader reader = comandoMySQL.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();
MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("idSocio"));
```

Como se pode ver, obtenho os dados de um campo de texto facilmente, como é o caso do campo "idSocio".
No caso do campo "fotoSocio", que na base de dados MySQL é do tipo LONGBLOB, como faço para o carregar para a source de um controlo image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo que encontrei e funcionou foi primeiramente você converte os `bytes` para um [`BitmapImage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
public BitmapImage BitmapImageFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    BitmapImage image = null;
    MemoryStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
        image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.StreamSource = ms;
        image.StreamSource.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        image.EndInit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        stream.Close();
        stream.Dispose();
    }
    return image;
}
```

Após essa conversão é só atribuir ao [`Source`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source(v=vs.110).aspx) do componente [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
MySqlConnection ligacaoBD = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;Pwd=123123;database=socios;persistsecurityinfo=True");
ligacaoBD.Open();
string cmd = string.Format("Select * from socios.socio WHERE idSocio={0}", 1);
MySqlCommand comandoMySQL = new MySqlCommand(cmd, ligacaoBD);
MySqlDataReader reader = comandoMySQL.ExecuteReader();
reader.Read();

byte[] foto = (byte[])reader["foto"];
image.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
image.Source = BitmapImageFromBytes(foto);

MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("idSocio"));
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tens uma possivel resposta, a funcao devolve a imagem em bitmap [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257941/retrieve-longblob-from-mysql-in-c-sharp)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257941/retrieve-longblob-from-mysql-in-c-sharp

edit:
podes tambem converter num array de bytes e serializar

```
 Model.ByteArray = (byte[])reader.GetString("fotoSocio")
```

e na view..

```
 @{
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.ByteArray);
var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);
 }

 <img src="@imgSrc" />
```